# Use method parameters and using it in another method?

Tags: java

(Hard to explain, sorry :P)

I want this method to take a title and message from the user and create a window using the title and message.

```
private void displayError()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(Title);
    frame.setSize(500, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel jlabel = new JLabel(Message, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(jlabel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public void throwError(String Title, String Message)
{
    displayError();
}
```

However, when I run it, it comes up with a blank screen when I use:

```
throwError("Test", "This is a test.")
```

How would I get this to work using the Title and Message from throwError()?

Edit: I use displayError() multiple times throughout my code, which is why I don't want to make it one method.

Ex:

```
public void folderCreation()
{
    String Title = "Folder not created";
    String Message = "The required folder could not be created by this application";
    displayError();
}

public void cancel()
{
    Title = "Cancelling";
    Message = "Cancelling the current process. Do not turn off your PC.";
    displayError();
}

public void GenericError()
{
    Title = "Generic Error";
    Message = "The application has experienced an error and we don't what caused it.";
    displayError();
}
```

The methods above work perfectly fine, but throwError() doesn't.

Comment: Why can't you just have one method?

Comment: I have more than one method using displayError(). For example, see the edited post.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think see the purpose of `throwError`. 1) It doesn't throw anything 2) it does nothing with the parameters 3) you could move all the code from `displayError` into `throwError` and it would work

Comment: Also, try to use a JOptionPane... Error popup  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64252/95515

Answer (score 1):

That is because the **scope** of the `Title` and `Message` is only within the `throwError()` method. You should put 2 parameters to the `displayError()` method like so:

```
private void displayError(String Title, String Message)..
```

And pass the `throwError()` arguments to it when called:

```
public void throwError(String Title, String Message)
{
    displayError(Title, Message);
}
```

Comment: `throwError` is a useless method though, better to just get rid of it and call `displayError` directly.

Comment: Yea, simply provide the data to the constructor directly of having some auxiliary method which doesn't do anything.

Comment: Delegating to one method of the same signature? Why?

Comment: Yeah I know it's  useless, but I just answered what OP asked for. No more no less. :)